# How to calculate a distance between cities by postgis?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to use postgis for calculate distance between cities. For example, the distance between Moscow and SPb is ~637 km (via measure distance in Google Maps). When I use postgis:

```
select ST_Distance(
    ST_Point(59.925632, 30.327239),
    ST_Point(55.750352, 37.615717),
    true
);
```

then I get 895 km

Can anyone tell me, why such an error in this measurement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've reversed the lat/lon in the parameters for your `ST_Point`s:

```
geometry ST_Point(float x_lon, float y_lat);
```

More details at this PostGIS [link](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html).